# Excel VBA to sum with multiple criteria for ( 500k row )

Tags: excel, vba, sum

i use following code to sum monthly data 
But for some reason VBA running non stop, before adding last criteria it worked fine for me.

```
Sub aqua()
    Dim Markets As Worksheet
    Set Markets = Sheets("sheet4")
    Sheets("DATA").Range("A:A").Name = "list1"
    Sheets("DATA").Range("L:L").Name = "list2"
    Sheets("DATA").Range("M:M").Name = "Printed"
    Sheets("DATA").Range("E:E").Name = "list3"
    Sheets("sheet4").Range("AP:AP").Name = "list4"
    Markets.Range("c1:c20").Name = "MARKET"
    Sheets("DATA").Cells(4, "V") = [sum(if((isnumber(match(list1,market,0)))*(list2>0)*(list1<>"")*(not(isnumber(match(list4,list3,0)))),printed))]
End Sub
```

Comment: what is `printed`?

Comment: printed is income from markets

Comment: ah yes. you'd better add the previously woorking code and some info about your goal and/or data layout

Comment: previous code was  
 = [sum(if((isnumber(match(list1,market,0)))*(list2>0)*(list1<>"")*(not(isnumber(match(list3,list4,0)))),printed))]
i changed (list3,list4,0) to (list4,list3,0) because thats giving me correct results. formula works fine as formula but when i use it on VBA it is running non-stop

Comment: edit your question to insert the previous code, and show a significant and concise example of your data layout and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is not the best tool for handling great amounts of data, like 500 k rows are

Moreover, you're actually handling 1 million rows since you are referencing *whole* columns (e.g. "A:A", "L:L", ...)

Hence a possible enhancement could be limiting the number of rows to the actual minimum one, as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub aqua()
    Dim Markets As Worksheet:  Set Markets = Worksheets("Sheet4")
    Dim DATA As Worksheet: Set DATA = Worksheets("DATA")

    Dim list1Rows As Long, list2Rows As Long, list4Rows As Long, printedRows As Long, nRows As Long

    list1Rows = GetLastRowIndex(DATA, "A")
    list2Rows = GetLastRowIndex(DATA, "L")
    printedRows = GetLastRowIndex(DATA, "M")
    list4Rows = GetLastRowIndex(DATA, "AP")
    nRows = WorksheetFunction.Max(list1Rows, list2Rows, list4Rows, printedRows) ' get the actual maximum rows number for "matching" list

    With DATA
        .Range("A1").Resize(nRows).Name = "list1" '
        .Range("L1").Resize(nRows).Name = "list2"
        .Range("M1").Resize(nRows).Name = "Printed"

        .Range("E1").Resize(GetLastRowIndex(DATA, "E")).Name = "list3"
    End With

    With Markets
        .Range("AP1").Resize(nRows).Name = "list4"
        .Range("c1:c20").Name = "MARKET"
    End With


    DATA.Cells(4, "V") = [sum(if((isnumber(match(list1,market,0)))*(list2>0)*(list1<>"")*(not(isnumber(match(list4,list3,0)))),printed))]
End Sub

Function GetLastRowIndex(sht As Worksheet, colName As String) As Long
    With sht
        GetLastRowIndex = .Cells(.Rows.Count, colName).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

in any case, 500K rows are quite a big amount of data and you'll still face time issues